# Using Blazor Is it safe to put IJSRuntime insite _Import.razor

Tags: blazor

How safe to inject the IJSRuntime inside the _import.razor

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using MyBlazorApp

**@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime**
```

Comment: I don't know if it is 'safe' but it certainly isn't a good idea. Don't inject what you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

The _import.razor file will include all the using statements in every page/component.

Unless you are definitely needing JavaScript runtime on every page, I would suggest it would be better to put it on the pages only where it will be used.

Otherwise it is being injected when not required.

Comment: I think everyone knows this. I'm pretty sure the question is if this opening a security hole.